# JQuery UI sortable scroll to bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've an issue with few sortable tables
Here's the initialization of the sortable object :

```
var conf = {
    helper: fixHelperModified,
    handle: ".moveTargetDeliverables",
    containment: "#fieldset_deliverables_summary",
    tolerance:'pointer'
}

$("#deliverables_summary tbody").sortable(conf);
```

When I drag an element it scrolls down automatically to the bottom of the page.

It only happens using Firefox and Chrome, works well under IE

I'm using JQuery UI 1.11.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add scroll:false in the conf object

```
var conf = {
helper: fixHelperModified,
handle: ".moveTargetDeliverables",
containment: "#fieldset_deliverables_summary",
...
scroll: false,
...
tolerance:'pointer'
}
```

It sounds weird, but it might be the thing you missed.

Comment: Just tested this under Chrome, FF, IE no problem at all

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the sortable with the scroll option specified:

```
$( "#deliverables_summary tbody" ).sortable({
  scroll: false
});
```

Get or set the scroll option, after initialization:

```
// Getter
var scroll = $( "#deliverables_summary tbody" ).sortable( "option", "scroll" );

// Setter
$( "#deliverables_summary tbody" ).sortable( "option", "scroll", false );
```

[You should read here](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-scroll)

Comment: Actually I didn't know there was a scroll option for this widget...Thank you !